# How to extract a string that has certain specific pattern with mix of dynamic and static characters in Python using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string as below

> 33f04e43cc6","from":"/ABC001/data/ZZZ000_logger_v1_20221010053935242_1.zip","to":"/ABC001/data/ZZZ000_logger_v1_20221010053935242_1.zip","remove":true,"objectId":"229bea5a-c9b0-4ad0-aecc-84a63bc7dc6f"}2022-10-10
> 05:39:35,247 Platform.Interface:  Published message to topic:
> {"id":"a32e6cbe-94d4-493f-ae56-933f04e43cc6"},
> "from":"/ABC001/data/ZZZ000_single_3445442_1.zip"

I need to extract file names *ZZZ000_logger_v1_20221010053935242_1.zip*,  *ZZZ000_single_3445442_1.zip* from this.

I have just shared a snapshot of the string. I used to get more file names in that pattern. In the above example, 'logger_v1' and 'single' strings will always be present in the mentioned format in the string

So the format of the filenames will be like that only as mentioned

```
AnyAlphanumericCharacter_logger_v1_AnyNumeric_1.zip
AnyAlphanumericCharacter_single_AnyNumeric_1.zip
```

I tried using regex as below

```py
match = re.findall("^\W.*zip$", str)
```

It will output *`/ABC001/data/ZZZ000_logger_v1_20221010053935242_1.zip`*

I am not sure how to provide dynamic and static characters search patterns in regex.

I will have list of file names like that and need to remove duplicates at the end.

Comment: Your regex [does not](https://regex101.com/r/LpUg9o/1) match your string, but you say get some output. So, please post the text you are using.

Comment: Use `\w` instead of `\W` like `\w+\.zip` https://regex101.com/r/NrGB96/1

Comment: Would it be accurate to state that the prefix for the file name is *any alphanumeric character **except forward slash (`/`) and period (`.`)."**?

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
In [1]: re.match(r'.*data/([^"]+).*', s).group(1)
Out[1]: 'ZZZ000_logger_v1_20221010053935242_1.zip'
```

Regex diagram. [Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/TFej4DdCSiMq0cPV)
[image]

Comment: Thanks, and it's better. I might have a string like ''/ABC001/data/ZZZ000_single_v1_20221010053935242_1.zip /ABC001/data/ZZZ000_logger_3445442_1.zip" this. And using the above one I will get 'ZZZ000_logger_3445442_1.zip'. But my objective is to select 'ZZZ000_single_v1_20221010053935242_1.zip' alone.

Comment: Thanks based on this I did as mentioned in my answer. It helped a lot.

Comment: @KBNanda Sorry I just saw your comment. Glad that you resolved the issue. When I get time I will update my answer for the above use case as well.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Rahul I used it in a similar pattern with slight changes.

```
regex = re.compile(".{0,}data/([^\"]{1,}).{0,}")
testString = '*****'
matchArray = regex.findall(testString)
```

Then I got all the matching file names with *.zip as an iterable array.

Thanks!